# Redirecting output to std output or /dev/null depending on optional parameter

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script where you can run it just like this `./myscript` and the output of some commands called inside the script are hidden, just like this:

```
if mvn tomcat:deploy &> /dev/null; then
```

But if the script is executed like this `./myscript -v` you can see the output of the commands, so it would be just:

```
if mvn tomcat:deploy; then
```

So first, what's the value of the standard output so I can store either that value or `/dev/null` in a variable in order to make the call like this:

```
if mvn tomcat:deploy &> $output; then
```

And what's the best way to check the arguments? Do I need to literally check that `$1` equals the literall `-v` or there's a better approach (since options are so commoly used, I guess there are different meachanisms)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name standard output in a script shell using any of:

- `1`
- `/dev/stdout`
- `/proc/self/fd/1`

All are just ways of saying "file descriptor #1", which is the conventional pre-opened data sink for output.

(In fact, the redirect syntax `>` just changes that pre-opened fd so that when the subcommand tries to write to fd 1, it actually goes to some other file or device.  `>&` does the same to both descriptors 1=stdout and 2=stderr.)

If you have just the one flag, there's nothing wrong with just checking `$1`.  There are several ways to do commandline option processing, but one powerful tool is `getopt`.  To get familiar with that, start by looking through `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely suggest using bash's `getopts` for processing any command line options - there's a [Small getopts tutorial at wiki.bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) which I found very helpful.

For the output redirection, instead of storing the file descriptor(s), you can just conditionally redirect the stream(s) before the body of your script or (possibly more cleanly), just close the stream(s) using `exec n>&-` where *n* is the numeric file descriptor of the stream (1 = stdout, 2 = stderr).

IMHO it would be more natural to keep output when the command is run with no arguments, and have a `-q` (quiet) option to dump output to /dev/null - for example

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":q" opt; do
  case $opt in
    q) 
      quiet=1
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done

if [ "${quiet:-0}" -ne 0 ]; then
   exec 1>&- 2>&-
fi

#
# remainder of your script here
#
```

If you're convinced you want to do the opposite (i.e. send stdout and stderr to /dev/null by default) then you can flip the logic.